# Avoid ambiguous rule match when editing same element in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to add an attribute to a  element, if the element should not be removed from the transformation. I thought my current XSL would satisfy this, by first discarding all elements that's not in the allowedArticles variable, and then adding the attribute to the elements that are left.

This however, does not work, and I am not sure how I would go about doing it correctly. I want to do both, discard the entire element if not in allowedArticles, and add an attribute to it if it should be in the transformation.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

This is my example XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:escenic="http://xmlns.escenic.com/2009/import">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <!-- Fetch the array from an external file: allowedArticles.xml -->
  <xsl:variable
    name="allowedArticles"
    select="document('allowedArticles.xml')/allowedArticles/articleId" />

  <!-- Identity template, copies every element in source file -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Matches content items that are NOT in the allowedArticles array,
    and discards them by doing nothing-->
  <xsl:template match="escenic:escenic/escenic:content[not(@exported-dbid=$allowedArticles)]" />

  <!-- Removes section-ref elements from within content elements -->
  <xsl:template match="escenic:escenic/escenic:content/escenic:section-ref" />

  <!-- Add delete-relations attribute to all content elements -->
  <xsl:template match="escenic:escenic/escenic:content">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="delete-relations">
        <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Consider to post a small but representative sample of XML input, the output you want and the one you currently get. Are you getting warnings from your XSLT processor about ambiguous rules?

Comment: I will remember to do that next time. Yes, I was getting ambiguous errors from Saxon, but the answer from @helderdarocha is correct. I just had to negate the predicate in the second template matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted one problem. It might not be the only one since I don't know what your source files look like.

Your second template removes the articles you do not want, but your last template, it seems, processes all of them again. You can fix this adding a predicate:

```
<xsl:template match="escenic:escenic/escenic:content[@exported-dbid=$allowedArticles]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="delete-relations">
            <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two template rules:

```
<xsl:template match="escenic:escenic/escenic:content
                    [not(@exported-dbid=$allowedArticles)]" />

<xsl:template match="escenic:escenic/escenic:content">
```

Although it's obvious to you and me that the first rule matches a subset of the nodes matched by the second, according to the XSLT spec they both have the same priority. So if you want the first one to take precedence, give them explicit priorities, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="escenic:escenic/escenic:content
                    [not(@exported-dbid=$allowedArticles)]" priority="6"/>

<xsl:template match="escenic:escenic/escenic:content" priority="5">
```

Alternatively I suspect the parent element qualifier is just noise, so you could write the rules as:

```
<xsl:template match="escenic:content
                    [not(@exported-dbid=$allowedArticles)]" />

<xsl:template match="escenic:content">
```

If you did that, the system would compute default priorities that reflect the selectivity correctly, so you wouldn't need to add a manual priority.

Of course, making the rules mutually exclusive as suggested by @helderadocha is another possibility, but in general with XSLT that's hard to achieve, so understanding and using template rule priorities is important.

Comment: I haven't tested this as of now(I will), but would it yield the same result to use priority? I thought that it would then give priority to the one with highest priority, and not perform the second matching at all?

Comment: I assume all escenic:content elements are to be processed using one template rule or the other but not both? My solution will do just that. It will use the higher priority template if it matches the element, and the lower priority rule if not.

Comment: That was what I thought. No, the escenic:content elements that are the negation of the first template rule should be processed with the second template rule.